# sklearn truncated svd not working for complex matrices

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, linear-algebra, svd

I'm trying to use the randomized version of sklearn's [TruncatedSVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) (although I'm actually calling the internal function randomized_svd to get the actual u, s, v matrices). While it is working fine for real matrices, for complex matrices I can't get back the original matrix even though the singular values are exactly correct:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.utils.extmath import randomized_svd
>>> N = 3
>>> a = np.random.rand(N, N)*(1 + 1j)
>>> u1, s1, v1 = np.linalg.svd(a)
>>> u2, s2, v2 = randomized_svd(a, n_components=N, n_iter=7)
>>> np.allclose(s1, s2)
True
>>> np.allclose(a, u1.dot(np.diag(s1)).dot(v1))
True
>>> np.allclose(a, u2.dot(np.diag(s2)).dot(v2))
False
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is a bug in randomized_svd, specifically on this transformation:

```
B = safe_sparse_dot(Q.T, M)
```

Replacing this by

```
B = safe_sparse_dot(Q.T.conj(), M)
```

solves the issue.